# Who delivering touchEvent to Activity?

Tags: android, touch

I know about touch event flow, when we are talking about Activity:

`Activity -> Window -> DecorView -> ViewGroup -> ...`

The question is: who delivering touch event to Activity, when user press smth on screen?

Is there any service or manager who respond for it?

Where can i read about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a [Looper](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20looper) running in ActivityThread receives an input-message from OS and dispatch input-event to the view hierarchy including Activity. Set a break point in onTouchEvent() and see "Frames" in Android Studio Debugger. You can find all the players (classes, methods) relevant to the event-delivery.